# Why the toast is not activated by pressing the button in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button, android-toast

I'm trying to display a toast when you click the button "boton_continuar" given the following conditions:
EditExt vacuum (numero_celular) and ckeckbox (check) check no. This is my code

```
boton_continuar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Verificamos que se halla clikeado y se halla ingresado
        if(check.isChecked() && numero_celular.getText().length() != 0){

            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, PrincipalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Context contexto = getApplicationContext();
            if(!check.isChecked()){                 
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe aceptar los términos", 2000);
            }
            if(numero_celular.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe ingresar su número", 2000);
            }
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Call `.show()` on the Toast you made.
2. `2000` is not a valid parameter for the Toast. That will not make it show up for 2000 ms. The only parameter that the Toast accepts for that is `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`

So:

Change these lines:

```
Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe aceptar los términos", 2000);
Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe ingresar su número", 2000);
```

to these lines:

```
Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe aceptar los términos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe ingresar su número", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` is 2000 ms (2 seconds), and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` is 3500 ms (3.5 seconds).

- `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT == 0` so you can pass is `0` instead.
- `Toast.LENGTH_LONG == 1` so you can pass it `1` instead.

Visit Android's documentation on [<kbd>Toast</kbd>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) for detailed information.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to call `.show()` after making your toast.

```
boton_continuar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Verificamos que se halla clikeado y se halla ingresado
        if(check.isChecked() && numero_celular.getText().length() != 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, PrincipalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Context contexto = getApplicationContext();
            if(!check.isChecked()){                 
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe aceptar los términos", 2000).show();
            }
            if(numero_celular.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe ingresar su número", 2000).show();
            }
        }
    }});
```

Comment: Note also that "2000" is not a valid second parameter to `makeText(...)`

Comment: "2000" is technically a valid second parameter, though not recommended. It will simply default to `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` (which, coincidentally, is 2000 ms).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SHOW function.

Do:

```
Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe ingresar su número", 2000).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ".show()" after your "Toast.makeText()"s.

For example:

```
if(!check.isChecked()){                 
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe aceptar los términos", 2000).show();
            }
            if(numero_celular.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe ingresar su número", 2000).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 boton_continuar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Verificamos que se halla clikeado y se halla ingresado
        if(check.isChecked() && numero_celular.getText().length() != 0){


            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, PrincipalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Context contexto = getApplicationContext();
            if(!check.isChecked()){                 
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe aceptar los términos", 2000).show();
            }
            if(numero_celular.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Debe ingresar su número", 2000).show();
            }


        }

    }});
```

You need to call `.show()` on the Toast for it to appear.